# Условие нахождение объекта в родителе

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как сделать следующее:
Загружаю картинки ajax и добавляю их в div

```
 $("#imagesPlaceholder").append(imgs);
```

по нажатию на картинку к ней присваивается класс  selimg ,а затем по нажатию кнопки они append в div с классом selected.Вопрос:как мне реализовать draggable and resizable изображений ,когда они внутри div с классом selected

Такой вариант не работает

```
if ($(imgs).parents(".selected")) {
                $(imgs).resizable();
                $('.ui-wrapper').draggable({
                    containment: 'parent'
                });

            }
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: "они append в div с классом selected". Интересный речевой оборот :)

Comment: А как в картинкой то мне поступить)